# How do I install Windows 7 on a MacBook Pro running OS X Sierra?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, macos, dual-boot

Sierra dropped Bootcamp support for pre-Windows 10. I've just reformatted and was running Windows 7 and OS X Sierra before the reformat but now I can't reinstall Windows 7. Is there a way to roll Bootcamp assistant back, or an easy way to reinstall?

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac. Generally, the 2015 and newer model Macs can not run Windows 7. This because Apple removed BIOS booting from the firmware which is required by Windows 7.

Comment: 2013, I was running Windows 7 before the reformat.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: @Alexey 盛安安's answer should be suitable!

Answer (score 2):

Update to macOS 10.12.2 or above in order to become nostalgic again.

> - Adds support for new installations of Windows 8 and Windows 7 using Boot Camp on supported Macs.

[About the macOS Sierra 10.12.2 Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207307)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way of installing win7 on your mbp.
Without burning the .iso to a dvd or creating a bootable USB.

wrote this guide just now since this was the only thing that worked for me.

good luck!
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1F4FWB6V6Ek6pGb4yDJ2l9QrsJLoW-2uEKhz-uMhzr3c/edit

Answer (score 0):

I find this answer helpful getting Win 7 installed.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7685609?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you're looking for.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016

The bootcamp files are available to be downloaded manually and then used during the USB bootable created by bootcamp.

Comment: This does not work, when I get to step 7 Boot Camp Assistant tells me "Need 64-bit Windows 10 or later ISO file."

Comment: That is correct. You need an ISO, either from a Windows 7 dvd, or from an .iso file. Microsoft used to offer iso file downloads for 7. However I don't know about now.

Comment: I have my Windows 7 iso, Boot Camp Assistant will not accept it and tells me "Need 64-bit **Windows 10** or later ISO file."

Comment: https://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/ May help there. I sadly don't have the time to read through everything. I'm sorry.

Comment: Can you delete your answer so this shows up as unanswered please? I initially tried the link you posted and Boot Camp Support as well as lots of googling, which is why I posted the question here.

Comment: Well, after taking the time to try it myself, the tables in the link I posted does indeed point to where I first saw they did. A link to a pervious bootcamp assist version. Find your model, and Windows bit type for your ISO, and download the bootcamp version.

Comment: Once again, **this does not work**. I don't know how much more clearly I can communicate this. The tables in your link lead to a download of a particular "bootcamp" set of drivers to be installed **after** Windows installation, which is different than a previous version of bootcamp assistant.